# MEVN Stack Redirecting to Home page after singing up

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, redirect, vuejs2

I'm currently stuck creating a site's sign up function.
I'm using the MEVN stack and I've managed to get my Front End working with my database, but once that's done, I get a

`cannot POST users/signup`

Let me show you show you the pertinent code:

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  //Verify if user email is associated with an account.
  User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      //Returns message if user email is associated with an account.
      if(user.length >= 1) {
        getCode.fourHundred(res, 409, 
          'This email is already associated with an account.');
      } else { //If email is not found, makes a hashed password value. 
        if(req.body.password !== 'undefined') {
          bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
            if(err) {
              getCode.fiveHundred(res, err);
            } else {
              //If no errors occur, creates a new user. 
              const user = new User({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash
              });
              // Saves user information to Database. 
              user.save()
              .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                getCode.twoHundred(res, 201, 'User created')
                return res.redirect(301, 'localhost:8080')
              })
              .catch(getCode.fiveHundred(res, err))
            }
          });
        } 
      }
    });
});
```

My front end is as follows:

```
<template>
  <main class="container">
    <h1> Sign Up</h1>
    <form class="grid-container" action="/users/signup" method="POST">
      <label class="label" for="first-name">First Name:</label>
      <input
        id="first-name"
        type="text"
        class="first-name input form-control"
        placeholder="First Name"
        v-model="firstName"
        required>

      <label class="label" for="last-name" >Last Name:</label>
      <input id="last-name"
         type="text"
         class="last-name input form-control"
         placeholder="Last Name"
         v-model="lastName"
         required>
      <label class="label" for="email" >Email:</label>
      <input id="email"
         type="email"
         class="email input form-control"
         placeholder="example@example.com"
         v-model="email"
         required>
      <label class="label" for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password"
         type="password"
         class="password input form-control"
         placeholder="Password"
         v-model="password"
         required>
      <div class="button-grid">
        <button
          class="button"
          type="submit"
          @click="signUp">
            Sign Up
        </button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService.js'

export default {
  name: 'SignUp',
  data () {
    return {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async signUp () {
      const response = await AuthenticationService.signUp({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
      console.log(response)
      setTimeout(() => this.redirect(), 1000)
    },
    redirect () {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'BuyAndSell' })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using axios to connect the front end to the Back End.

```
export default () => axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
})
```

```
import api from '@/services/api'

export default {
  signUp (credentials, res) {
    return api().post('/users/signup', credentials)
  }
}
```

I tried redirecting through Vue and I tried through express but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Edit: I'm also adding this code because these are some functions that I refactored to clean my code a bit.

```
const getFiveHundredErrors = (res, err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  };

  const getfourHundredErrors = (res, code, message) => {
    return res.status(code).json({
      message: message
    })
  };

  const getTwoHundredSuccessCodes = (res, code, output, token) => {
    return res.status(code).json({
      output: output,
      token: token || null
    })

  }

  module.exports = { 
    fiveHundred: getFiveHundredErrors, 
    fourHundred: getfourHundredErrors, 
    twoHundred: getTwoHundredSuccessCodes }
```

This is the app.js file.
I'm getting in my console a 500 error which is probably the one in the .catch() maybe the error is there? But I'm not sure how to get the code to redirect back to the Home page after the users are created. Also, even though the users are being created, the 200 status isn't being shown to me either.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/users');
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
const savedItemsRoutes = require('./api/routes/savedItems');

//I removed the mongodb.connect function to avoid exposing that info, even though I have the password stored in a .env file. 

//Middleware.
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
  'Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
    'PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'GET');
    return res.status(200/json({}));
  }
  next();
});

// Request Handling Routes. 
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/savedItems', savedItemsRoutes);
```

**Other issue:**
I sort of understand what’s going on here but I'm not sure where I can fix it yet. I know I have to return some res.status once the original response has been sent, but I'm just a bit confused about what the flow of my code is and I'm trying to follow where the error message takes me but I'm just clueless at this point.

```
(node:28036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/edgarnegron/Projects/llevatelopr/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/edgarnegron/Projects/llevatelopr/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/edgarnegron/Projects/llevatelopr/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at getTwoHundredSuccessCodes (/Users/edgarnegron/Projects/llevatelopr/server/api/routes/users.js:112:20)
    at /Users/edgarnegron/Projects/llevatelopr/server/api/routes/users.js:40:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: This code is not pertinent to the error.  Can you show where you handle your `users/signup` route in Express?  Something in the form of `app.post('users/signup', ...`  This message basically means no such route handler exists.

Comment: @dan Yes, I understand what you mean. However, I am able to see the console logs whenever I create a user on my database and when I go to mongoose the users are being created. I'm not sure how to make the redirect after that to my home page.

Comment: @dan I had posted the whole thing but a format error didn't display it, I fixed it now. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: You're saying you create a user even though Express says it can't find the route, or you create the user some other way?  You should show any `/users` routes as well.

Comment: Yeah, in the code I wrote for the /signup route, I'm seeing the console.log(result) from the .then() being printed out on my console and my mongoDB database being filled with the users. let me show you my app.js file. I'm guessing that the error is somewhere around the getCode status code utilities I built.

Comment: The problem is that's not possible:  if it can't find the route, it can't run the route code.  I see what's happening now.  On closer inspection it looks like you're actually doing two things on form submit:  1 from the click (`signUp` method:  this is probably creating the user, though I can't see the service code) and 1 from the form `action`.  This is bad design for 2 reasons.  You shouldn't spawn 2 separate calls like this, and you shouldn't use form action this way or you'll leave your single page app.  There's also both a frontend and backend redirect. This is all conflicting with itself

Comment: @dan thanks for pointing this out to me. I am honestly no Back End developer and I appreciate your feedback so much. What would be the best practice. I should eliminate the action and which redirect should I remove from my code. I really wasn't thinking of leaving both there but just blindly trying to see what worked. I should have definitely not tried doing both ways at the same time.

Comment: Remove the form action/method completely.  That is what takes you away from the SPA (and to a wrong route showing the error message).  In general, you don't use form action with a SPA like Vue because it takes you off the app.  Your Authentication service is successfully creating a user so everything should be ok if you see the `console` message in the `signUp` method.

Comment: @dan thank you so much. I fixed the issue, I have an additional one that I've been going at for a while as well, I'm trying to fix it on my own but if you could also hint me to what it could be I would be really grateful.

Comment: First let me submit this as an answer for you to accept

Comment: @dan ^^ Obviously fixed it thanks to your help. Before you wrote this message, I figured that that was what I had to do as per your suggestion. Thank you so much, I've been trying to fix this for almost a week. You're a live saver.

Comment: You're welcome.  I edited the answer for your second question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form action sends you away from the SPA and to a wrong route.  And you're actually doing two things on form submit:

1) The click action calls a `signUp` method.  This is creating the user, though we can't see the service code.

2) The form action

This is bad design for 2 reasons. You shouldn't spawn 2 separate calls like this, and you shouldn't use form action this way or you'll leave your single page app. There's also both a frontend and backend redirect. Remove the form action/method completely. That is what takes you away from the SPA (and to a wrong route showing the error message). In general, you don't use form action with an SPA because it takes you off the app.

## Question 2

Change your post-save code to:

```
user.save()
  .then(result => {
    return res.status(201).send(result);
  })
```

This will set the status and send back the user you just created, as long as `save` returns it as well.  There's no need for the 301.